# What does "to be in position" mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I have a customer from the US. Recently I conducted a test which showed that someone should investigate configuration of the system and apply changes to it. After that I received the following response:

> "Please let us know if there is anything we can do. Let us know when you’re **in a position** for us to make the change and re-run the test to confirm that we are receiving better results."

I have difficulties with this part: "you’re in a position for us to make the change". **I don't clearly understand who should make the change: I or someone else?**

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, 'to be in [a] position for' means 'to be ready for'. [It can also be meant more literally -- 'to be in the position you need to be in']

*They* are going to make the change, but only when you let them know that you're ready for it to be made.